# Как получить список имен колонок в mysqli?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Могу ли я как-то при работе с mysqli в php получить массив имен колонок результата в правильном порядке? В результате JOIN имена некоторых из них могут совпадать.

Comment: Чем вас не устроили [fetch_field_direct](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-field-direct.php) и [fetch_field](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-field.php)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если у Вас есть объект `mysqli_result`, то доступ к метаданным запроса осуществляется при помощи методов `mysqli_result::fetch_fieldXXX`

Объект `mysqli_result` можно получить функциями `mysqli_query()`, `mysqli_store_result()`, `mysqli_use_result()`. Или функцией `mysqli_stmt_result_metadata()`, если вы используете prepared statements.

Список полей в объекте `field` следующий:

- name  Имя столбца
- orgname   Исходное имя столбца, если у него есть псевдоним
- table Имя таблицы, которой принадлежит столбец (если не вычислено)
- orgtable  Исходное имя таблицы, если есть псевдоним
- max_length    Максимальная ширина поля результирующего набора.
- length    Длина поля в байтах, как она задана при определении таблицы. Обратите внимание, что данная величина(в байтах) может отличаться от величины в символах, указанной в опредлелении поля таблицы, так как в разных кодировках один символ может может записываться несколькими байтами. Например, поле VARCHAR(10) в кодировке UTF-8 вернет длину 30 = 10 символов * 3 байта на символ, а для кодировки LATIN1 - длину 10, так как в этой кодировке один символ занимает один байт.
- charsetnr Числовой идентификатор кодировки.
- flags Целое число, представляющее битовые флаги для поля.
- type  Тип данных поля
- decimals  Число знаков после запятой (для целочисленных полей)

Answer (score 2):

Используйте alias.

```
select 
    t1.name as name1,
    t2.name as name2
from table_one as t1, table_two as t2
```

Перечисляйте все интересующие поля из выборки, совпадающие выбирайте под алиасом